# Grouped Bar Chart ChartJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs, chart.js

I am very new to using ChartJs as a JavaScript library and I am having some difficulties with making a grouped bar chart that reads each JSON object and places as its own tick on the X-axis.

It's really hard to explain but I want to take Monday's JSON object as an example and I want to display Monday on the X-Axis and everything after I want to be on the chart as a grouped bar chart (I want the original_tweet, retweets, etc. on the chart).

However right now its just duplicating it.

---

**index.html :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <canvas id="myChart" style="width: 100%; height: auto;"></canvas>
</div>
<div id="js-legend" class="chart-legend"></div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/chartJsControl.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**chartJsControl.js :**

```
$.getJSON("data.json", function (json) {
    // will generate array with ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday']
    var labels = json.map(function (item) {
        return item.timestamp;
    });
    var tweet = json.map(function (item) {
        return item.original_tweet;
    });
    var data = {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [{
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
            highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
            highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: tweet
        }, {
            label: "My Second dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
            highlightFill: "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
            highlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data: tweet
        }]
    };
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
    ctx.canvas.width = 1000;
    ctx.canvas.height = 800;
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(data);
});
```

**data.json :**

```
[{
    "timestamp": "Monday",
    "original_tweet": "756",
    "retweets": "345",
    "shared": "34",
    "quoted": "14"
}, {
    "timestamp": "Tuesday",
    "original_tweet": "456",
    "retweets": "345",
    "shared": "34",
    "quoted": "14"
}, {
    "timestamp": "Wednesday",
    "original_tweet": "956",
    "retweets": "345",
    "shared": "34",
    "quoted": "14"
}]
```

**Screenshot :**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement, your **datasets** array in data variable should look like this :

```js
var data = {
    labels: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday'],
    datasets: [{
        label: "original_tweet",
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
        highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
        highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: [756,456,956]
    }, {
        label: "retweets",
        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
        highlightFill: "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
        highlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        data: [345,345,345]
    }, {
        label: "shared",
        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
        highlightFill: "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
        highlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        data: [34,34,34]
    }, {
        label: "quoted",
        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
        highlightFill: "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
        highlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        data: [14,14,14]
    }]
};
```

In datasets, you must categorize all the options you want to see as grouped bars. In your case **original_tweet, retweets, shared,quoted**.

Labels will be the points on X-axis. If somewhere data for some point on X-axis not available e.g *data of retweets not available for 'Monday'* then it will be 0 in retweet's **data** array like in below code:

```js
...
}, {
  label: "retweets",
    fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
    strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
    highlightFill: "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
    highlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    data: [0,345,345]
}, {
...
```